# Entity objects with helper properties

Tags: c#, domain-driven-design

In my domain model I have an Entity object that looks as follows:

```
public class Group
{
    public int idGroup { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
}
```

I have a repository for this object:

```
public class GroupRepository : IGroupRepository
{
    public Group LoadGroup(int idGroup)
    {
        //imitation of SQL data reader
        Group g = new Group();
        g.idGroup = Convert.ToInt32(r["idTipoGrupo"]);
        g.Description = Convert.ToString(r["Descricao"]);
        return g;
    }
}
```

But now I need to get some extra information from data store about Group objects through a new function in my created repository, here are the fields I need:

```
public bool HasChildGroups { get; set; }
public int ChildGroupsCount { get; set; }
public bool HasDeals { get; set; }
public int DealsCount { get; set; }
```

These properties look to me like a "service" or "helper" properties and I don't plan to use them everywhere in my application, only few times, but I need them. The simplest thing I could think of is that I added these "service" properties to my Group object and created a method in my repository that populates them. But I consider doing this wrong, as it is the Entity and I don't need them in here. So where should I keep such "service" objects? Do I have to create a new class that inherits from `Group` like this:

```
public class GroupHelper : Group
{
    public bool HasChildGroups { get; set; }
    public int ChildGroupsCount { get; set; }
    public bool HasDeals { get; set; }
    public int DealsCount { get; set; }
}
```

Or should I consider using some Data Transfer Objects?
How would you solve this problem?
Any help appreciated.

Comment: Your domain model doesn't seem to reflect the relationship between children and parent groups, nor between groups and deals. Is that normal ? Do you expect to leverage the repository and issue a database query each time you want to access a group's parent or children ?

Comment: @guillaume31: Yeah, I didn' include any additional properties and entities, they are irrelevant in my case, because I just need to know something up front about Group entity regardless future parent-child connections, that's why I used terms for this object like "service", "helper", "DTO".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first question to ask is how the state of the proposed `GroupHelper` object is managed. Attributes such as HasChildGroups seems like they would be altered as a result of behaviors invoked on a `Group` entity. If so, then they should be first class entities in your domain model, perhaps event part of the group entity itself. If the properties are managed outside of your domain model then you can just query that data as you would any other external data source. I would have this be a standalone object, perhaps called something like `GroupInfo` not extending Group itself.

What seems to be the issue here is that you have query requirements that aren't in alignment with the shape of your entities. In that case you have the flexibility to decouple your [read-models](http://gorodinski.com/blog/2012/04/25/read-models-as-a-tactical-pattern-in-domain-driven-design-ddd/) from your domain models. Read-models are intended to fulfill query requirements and your domain models are intended to host behavior associated with your domain.

Answer (score 1):

> HasChildGroups [...] look to me like a "service" or "helper" properties [...] But I consider doing this wrong, as it is the Entity and I don't need them in here.

If you concider your `Group` object to be a data access object and you have a separate model for, say, viewdata, you're right.

But this may also be a fat class, providing in view-specific *and* database-specific code. It's not plain wrong.

You could indeed create a `GroupDTO` class that provides the properties you require in the application but not for the data access, to separate concerns.